# Error in function for sortable list using local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am using this function with framework7 sortable lists to save the position of the order of the list, I can save them to local storage, but I can't read them, I got this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

And its reffering to this line:

```
if (ls[j] === itemsArr[i].dataset.id) {
```

Here's my full function:

```
var list = document.getElementById('my-id');
var items = list.children;
var itemsArr = [];
for (var i in items) {
itemsArr.push(items[i]);
}
// localStorage
var ls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data-user-sort') || '[]');

for (var j = 0; j < ls.length; j++) {
for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; ++i) {
  if (ls[j] === itemsArr[i].dataset.id) {
     list.appendChild(itemsArr[i]);
  }
}    
}


$('.list-block.sortable').on('sort', function () {
var newIdsOrder = [];
$(this).find('li').each(function(){
  newIdsOrder.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
});

localStorage.setItem('data-user-sort', JSON.stringify(newIdsOrder));
});
```

and here my html:

```
<div class="list-block sortable">
      <ul id="my-id">
        <li data-id="1">
          <a href="#" class="item-link item-content">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title">Item 1</div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="sortable-handler"></div>
        </li>
        <li data-id="2">
          <a href="#" class="item-link item-content">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title">Item 2</div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="sortable-handler"></div>
        </li>
        <li data-id="3"> 
          <a href="#" class="item-link item-content">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title">Item 3</div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="sortable-handler"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your itemsArr variable does not only contains "li" objects, so when you iterate over it, you end up trying to access to the "dataset" property on objects where it doesn't exist.

If you debug your javascript, you will see that you have 3 "li" classes, the list's length and 2 functions (item() and namedItem()) and because of that, you get that error after the third iteration.

As someone else already said, you first need to verify if the property exists, but the code that he provided you will fail because he's also checking the property id of dataset, which is an undefined value. This code should work for you:

```
for (var j = 0; j < ls.length; j++) {
  for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; ++i) {
    if(itemsArr[i].dataset !== undefined){
      if (ls[j] === itemsArr[i].dataset.id) {
         list.appendChild(itemsArr[i]);
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

You can also check this jsfiddle with that validation https://jsfiddle.net/7bv849wc/1/

**Edited because I forgot to add the index on itemsArr***

Comment: I am missing something here, I still get an error with your code too. `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have an "itemsArr.0" or something like that in your code? Because it seems like you're using that 0 as a property, not as an index.

Comment: I just added your code to the function, now it is like this: http://pastebin.com/raw/PYSAY7ix

Comment: That's weird, I don't get any error message in the jsfiddle. Can you provide the full code (both html and javascript) that you're using right now?

Comment: Sure, you can check it here: http://codepen.io/RogerHN/pen/wzrBba  It works saving the position of the list on local storage, but it fails to retrieve if you load the page.

Comment: Woops, in the code above, I put the index on dataset, instead of itemsArr, so, instead of being: 
itemsArr.dataset[i] !== undefined
it should be
itemsArr[i],dataset !== undefined. I already edited the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123184/discussion-between-rogerhn-and-esteban-cervantes).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't appear to be the local storage that is throwing the error but instead trying to access a property (dataset in your case) of an array element which is undefined.
You could check that the property is not undefined first:

```
  if ((itemsArr[i].dataset.id !== undefined) && ls[j] === itemsArr[i].dataset.id) {
```

You may wish to do additional checks on your data to prevemt these type of errors, hopefully this helps you back on track.

Comment: I changed the function with the code you provided and still got the same error. (I am newbie to javascript), but I think it's not reading the property right.

Comment: You may need to check the dataset property itemsArr[i].dataset !== undefined to see if that is undefined. This is what the error message is saying, no evidence to expect an error from localstorage in your question